# Windows 7 Visual Studio "windows 8.1 required" on new project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, windows-7

I ran into some time consuming problems.

So basically I've been using VS 2015 for a while on Win7 64bit.

I installed the "Windows 8 Tools" because I tried to debug something for another version of windows. I played a lot to make that work, I think I changed the toolset locations maybe, but I don't know where that is and what the default would be.

The problem is when I uninstalled the Win8 toolsets from my Control Panel, then when I tried to enter one of my project, it said I needed to upgrade to windows 8.1 to load this project.

Even if I try to create a new JavaScript project it tells me I need to upgrade to Windows 8,1.
There is a weird message this is the link: (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/183979885788659713/365283534644183065/unknown.png).
It says "Visual Studio 2013" I don't know why.

I've been googling for hours but I'm not even english and I don't find nothing I think my problem is too specific.

Maybe I miss something but can anyone help please?
Right now I'm desperate.
I uninstall with the cmd "D:\vs_entreprise.exe /uninstall /force"  then reinstall, restarted, reset all settings to default in the "export and import settings" but same problem.

Thank you,
rt-2

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? If you were expecting it to run on Windows 7, it has to be a Win32 desktop app. "Windows 8 Tools' is for Windows 8.x Store apps which have been replaced by UWP apps for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled all the framework I installed when I was trying to install the Win8 tools. Then VS told me that I was missing 4.6.something. I went into the CD and found "M:\packages\sdk_tools46\" and installed it, then I could open VS and create new projects. New projects are targeted for 10.